# Calculating monthly and annual stock returns for many firms in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance, panel-data

I am currently working on a project for my thesis, and I am working with a Pandas panel data containing multiple firms with their respective prices spanning across multiple months.

What I would like to do is:

1. To calculate monthly returns for each stock,
2. Annualise those monthly returns so that for each stock we can see the yearly commulative performance.

The panel data at the moment looks something like this:

```
Date       Ticker       Price 
03/2003    AAPL         30.214 
04/2003    AAPL         32.456 
05/2003    AAPL         38.002
06/2003    AAPL         37.328 
...        ...           ...   
08/2010    TSLA         238.421 
09/2010    TSLA         245.332 
10/2010    TSLA         239.713
...        ...           ...
```

Thus, I would like to create a column on the side showing the monthly stock price changes ( [t2/t1]-1 ). Given this, create a new pandas data frame with the annualised returns and corresponding ticker.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: You could use pct_change() to calculate returns.
pd.DataFrame.pct_change(periods=n) where n would be whatever you want to represent as a month.

Comment: Hey! Your comment definitely helped :) thanks for that!

Comment: Although I am still having trouble grouping the panel data based on the date to make it into a year :P

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to the annual return, with pandas there are many ways to do the same thing. This is one of the version. Please let me know if you need further clarification. Where `df` is your dataframe with the panel data

```
dfYearly = df.groupby(["Ticker", "Year"])["Date"].agg(["min", "max"]).reset_index()
dfYearly = dfYearly.merge(df[["Ticker", "Date", "Price"]], how="left", left_on=["Ticker", "min"], right_on=["Ticker","Date"])
dfYearly.rename(columns={"Price": "Price-Begin"}, inplace=True)
dfYearly.drop("Date", axis=1, inplace=True)
dfYearly = dfYearly.merge(df[["Ticker", "Date", "Price"]], how="left", left_on=["Ticker", "max"], right_on=["Ticker","Date"])
dfYearly.rename(columns={"Price": "Price-End"}, inplace=True)
dfYearly.drop(["Date", "min", "max"], axis=1, inplace=True)
dfYearly["Annual Return"] = np.round(dfYearly["Price-End"].values / dfYearly["Price-Begin"].values - 1, 3)
```